# VBA code for Print to PDF (print pages 1 to 3 only)

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code, and I am here to ask what I would need to add to the code to print pages 1 to 3 only?

```
Sub PrintVisa()

Dim invoiceRng As Range
Dim pdfile As String
'Setting range to be printed
Set invoiceRng = Range("C7:L175")
pdfile = " Seabourn_Visa_Letter"
invoiceRng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=pdfile, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: Is there any connection between your code and the question title? I mean, should the range `invoiceRng` be involved anyhow?

Comment: `to:=3` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.exportasfixedformat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub ExportFirstThreeSheets()
  Dim FileName As String
  FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MyThreeSheets.pdf"
   Sheets(Array(1, 2, 3)).copy 'it creates a new workbook containing the first three sheets
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, FileName, , , , , , True
        .Close False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What would I need to add to your code Fane to save the pdf file to a path location specified by cell in sheet 1?

Comment: @CarlS `FileName = Sheets("Sheet1").value`. It must be the full name... Otherwise, you can have the (common) folder path in a cell and the name in another one. Separated by "\"...

Comment: I get an error on the exportasfixedformat line, did I code it right?

Sub PrintVisa()

  Dim FileName As String
  MsgBox "Visa letter is now created, go to One Drive/Joiners Docs and move the letter into the candidate folder."
  FileName = Sheets("VV").Range("P2  ").Value & "\Seabourn_Visa_Letter.pdf"
   Sheets(Array(13)).Copy 'it creates a new workbook containing the first three sheets
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, FileName, , , , , , True
        .Close False
        
    End With

End Sub

Comment: @CarlS What do you expect from `Sheets(Array(13))`? Does the workbook to be processed have 13 sheets or more? Please insert the next code line after `FileName = ...`: `Debug.Print FileName: Stop`. What does it return in Immediate Window (being in VBE press `Ctrl + G` to open the window) when code stops on this line? Is it the path you need/want? If so, does the user running the code has permissions to write on that folder?

Comment: Yes, my spreadsheet has a lot of tabs.......I am loving your code by the way, it is awesome. I had a mail merge code before, but this negates the need of that code, so a HUGE thank you to you.

Comment: @CarlS Welcome! But you do not say anything about the source of your problem... That mentioned "mail merge code"?

Answer (score 1):

The ExportAsFixedFormat has a page range built in. See below:

Sheet5.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="YouFileName.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, ***From:=1, To:=3,*** OpenAfterPublish:=True